# How do I append some lines from several text files to another one?

Tags: perl, awk

I have got nine text files in a directory, each has 1000 lines. I want to take the first 500 lines from each, then write all of them in order to another text file, and take the rest (the last 500 lines) from each one to do the same I do before.

```
awk '{if (NR<=500) {print}}' 1.txt > 2.txt  # I do it 9 times, then I use cat to append.
awk '{if (NR>500) {print}}' 3.txt > 4.txt
```

or

```
awk 'NR>500' 3.txt > 4.txt
```

I did it with awk, but I want to learn Perl instead.

Comment: Far be it for my to do away with perl, but have you tried `head -n500 -q *.txt >first` and `tail -n500 -q *.txt >last`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -e 'open(F1,">1.txt");
open(F2,">2.txt");
foreach (@ARGV) {
open(F,"<$_");
while(<F>) {
print F1 $_ if ($. <= 500);
print F2 $_ if ($. > 500);
}
close(F);
}
close(F1);
close(F2);' <FILES>
```

Comment: algorithm is correct, but you should `use strict; use warnings;`, use `3 args open` and test for errors.

Comment: @M42: The only reason to use 3-arg open in this example is to set the encoding, nothing else.

Comment: i put my input file name like abc.txt here instead of $_:: open(F,"<$_"); but its not working, am i doin smthng wrong??

Comment: @M42 ... do you really write that for commandline scripting? This was aimed to mimic the awk script and be as simple as possible

Comment: @user683915: I am not sure what you mean? You mean you want to specify the inputfile in the script like `open(F,"<abc.txt")` intead of `$_ = "abc.txt"` coming from the `foreach (@ARGV)` ?

Answer (score 1):

In Perl `$.` has line number of last accessed filehandle. In `while ($. <=500 )` -cycle you can get wanted count of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation could agree with your example more. But based on the idea that you want all 9000 lines to go into a single file.

I didn't know where you were going to specify your names, so I used the command line.

```
use English qw<$OS_ERROR>;

open( my $out_h, '>', $outfile_name ) 
    or die "Could not open '$outfile_name'! - $OS_ERROR"
    ;

my @input_h;
foreach my $name ( @ARGV ) { 
    open( $input_h[ $_ ], '<', $name ) 
        or die "Could not open '$name'! - $OS_ERROR"
        ;
}
foreach my $in_h ( @input_h ) { 
    my $lines_written = 0;
    while ( $lines_written++ < 500 ) { 
        print $out_h scalar <$in_h>;
    }
}
foreach my $in_h ( @input_h ) { 
    print $out_h <$in_h>;
}
close $out_h;
close $_ foreach @input_h;
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in your last `print $out_h <$in_h>` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(F1,">1.txt");
open(F2,">2.txt");
open(F,"<$_");

while(<F>) {
print F1 $_ if ($. <= 500);
print F2 $_ if ($. > 500);
}
close(F);
close(F1);
close(F2);
```

i deleted foreach statement then it works, isnt that weird. thanks for ur help by the way..

Comment: If this worked for you, you can just upvote the answer - not repost it. Anyway I added the `perl -e` if you want to call it from the commandline like your awk command.